# How to write get and set methods for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a bit mixed up. Here is my work so far.

```
public class CourseYear
{
    private String courseName;
    private int year;
    private String tutorName;
    private String [] moduleList;
```

The moduleList is to hold 6 modules

```
public CourseYear()
{
    courseName = "Default";
    year = 0;
    tutorName = "Joe Bloggs";
    moduleList = new String [5];
}
```

This is where my problem lies, I'm not sure how to do the array parts:

```
public void addModule(Module newModule, int index)
{
    Module = newModule[0];
    Module = newModule[1];
    Module = newModule[2];
    Module = newModule[3];
    Module = newModule[4];
    Module = newModule[5];
}
```

I have no idea how to do the get methods

```
public Module getModule(int index)
{
    return Module[index];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reference your array with the index.  In your class definition you need a

`private Module[] modules = new Module[6]; // initialize`

If you want your Array to contain `Module` instances, the array needs to be an array of Modules. Right now your class has a `String` array.

and then your add method becomes

```
public void addModule(Module newModule, int index){
    this.modules[index] = newModule; // put the instance in the correct bucket
}
```

Note a few things:

1).  Your array has 6 buckets, so the indexes allowed are 0-5.  If index in the `addModule` method is out of bounds you will get an exception.

2).  `addModule` expects `newModule` to be a module instance.  So you use addModule like

```
CourseYear courseYear = new CourseYear(); // create a courseyear
courseYear.addModule(new Module(), 0); // create a module and add it at index 0
courseYear.addModule(new Module(), 1); // create a module and add it at index 1
...
```

You can also use `addModule` inside the `CourseYear` class.  Say you want to initialize in your constructor

```
public CourseYear(){
    this.addModule(new Module(), 0); // create a module and add it at index 0
    this.addModule(new Module(), 1); // create a module and add it at index 1
    ...
}
```

You should be able to figure out `getModule`

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class CourseYear
    {
        private String courseName;
        private int year;
        private String tutorName;
        private Module[] moduleList;

    public CourseYear()
    {
        courseName = "Default";
        year = 0;
        tutorName = "Joe Bloggs";
        moduleList = new Module[6];
    }

    public void addModule(Module newModule, int index)
    {
        moduleList[index] = newModule;
    }


    public Module getModule(int index)
    {
        return moduleList[index];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1.If you want to hold 6 values in moduleList, you should instantiate with `new String[6]`.

2.You will simplify your life by using an object of type `List<String>` instead of having to maintain an index and so forth:

```
 List<String> moduleList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It's dynamic and simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to write get and set methods for moduleList. The signatures would be

```
public void setModuleList(String[] module);

public String[] getModuleList();
```

Once you get the list, you can retrieve the items in the list.